# Where is Tableau Service Manager installed with Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I have an Ubuntu machine running Tableau Server. The server is up and running fine at the moment. However, I need to stop it to made some modifications to the server configuration.

When I run `tsm stop` in my shell, `tsm` is not found. Another engineer installed Tableau Server on the machine so I'm not very familiar with it.

Where is `tsm` located in the Tableau files? If it's not on my machine, can I install it easily and separately to the server?

If installing `tsm` is not possible, how can I stop and start Tableau Server safely while also not restarting the entire machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package installer includes a file you can source to set up paths and other environment variables.  The source command can be added to your login shell's configuration, i.e. `~/.bashrc`, to happen automatically at login.

```
$ source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh
```

The default installation for Tableau server packages includes a long version string.  The values used for the current package installation can be read from the environment.bash file.

Examples for Tableau server 2021.2.1

```
$ cat /etc/opt/tableau/tableau_server/environment.bash
# Tableau Server global initialization parameters
TABLEAU_SERVER_DATA_DIR="/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server"
TABLEAU_SERVER_CONFIG_NAME="tabsvc"
TABLEAU_SERVER_DATA_DIR_VERSION="20212.21.0712.0907"
TABLEAU_SERVER_UNPRIVILEGED_USERNAME="tableau"
TABLEAU_SERVER_TSM_AUTHORIZED_GROUPNAME="tsmadmin"
TABLEAU_SERVER_USERS_AND_GROUPS_CREATED="1"
$ which tsm
/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.20212.21.0712.0907/tsm
```